# Jquery Address problems in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-address

I have problems with Jquery Address in IE 7 and 8.
I did like that:

```
<script>
$.address.crawlable(false);
$.address.state('/');
$.address.strict(false);
$.address.parameter("param", "new_value");
</script>
```

In browsers is like this: `www.site.com/?param=new_value`

but, only IEs is like this: `www.site.com/#?param=new_value`

and still does the redirection the site, Anyone know how to solve this? I've looked at the documentation, but found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: As `$.address` is no part of core jquery you might want to add which plugin you're using.

Comment: Looks like the jQuery address plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem:

```
<script>
$.address.state('/');
$.address.value("?param=new_value");
</script>
```

In IE displays like this:
www.site.com/#/?param=new_value

Out of curiosity, because in IE it adds the hash (#)?
Thanks